# Adding an element to top of a group element

Tags: d3.js

After joning data with my group I would like the elements in the `enter` selection to be added to a group (`g`-element) on top/highest up. Default is to append to the bottom.

The reason for this is that I want the object to visually appear below the all ready visible objects.

I know I can order and sort but I thought there might be an easier/better way to do this. I have done several manual things only to later find out "Oooh, they included a smart way to do that, EASILY."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

D3 does have an `insert` method: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-insert

Comment: Very good. Exaclty what I was looking for. Changing '.append("g")' to '.insert("g",":first-child")' did the trick.

Comment: @GusOst Your answer is exactly what I was looking for (at-least an hour)

Comment: That links dead.  Inset can be found at https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_insert

Answer (score 13):

## Excerpt from Reference

For instance, `insert("div", ":first-child")` will prepend child div
nodes to the current selection.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-insert