# Apply z-index to SVG path

Tags: css, svg, z-index

Is there a way how to apply z-index on a SVG path?

I have simple SVG arrow:

```
<svg class="arrow">
  <path class="line" />
  <path class="endpoint"/>
</svg>
```

If I use css to chnge z-index of the whole `.arrow` everything works fine, but when I try to apply it only on `.endpoint` it doesn't work.

Is there some solution or workaround for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe everything will be relative to the svg canvas and not other dom elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use z-index in svg elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786618/how-to-use-z-index-in-svg-elements)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As an alternative, you can use "< use >"

Example:

```
<svg>
    <circle id="shape1" cx="20" cy="50" r="40" fill="yellow" />
    <rect id="shape2" x="4" y="20" width="200" height="50" fill="grey" />
    <circle id="shape3" cx="70" cy="70" r="50" fill="blue" />
    <use id="use" xlink:href="#shape2" />
</svg>
```

The shape2 layer will be the top most layer.

Comment: but you have 2 elements (#shape2 cloned!). what about 100 elements? try a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526837/4935426)

Answer (score 18):

There's no z-index in SVG, it uses [painters model](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/render.html#PaintersModel). You'd have to remove the path from the DOM and re-add it before any elements that should be on top of it and after any elements that it should be on top of.

As you've discovered z-index only works on the complete `<svg>` content as the html renderer controls how that is positioned before handing off to the SVG renderer to draw the internal SVG contents.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a dire need to do it, you can define an explicit compositing order using alternate filter effects (as long as you don't need support in Firefox or IE.)

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "define an explicit compositing order using alternate filter effects " (a link or example would be great!). This could be useful for a project I'm working on - specifically, I'm trying to avoid flicker on a 3d-like carousel of SVG elements that contain clipped images. To get the z-stacking right, I have to re-order them, and this seems to cause the flicker as each image gets reloaded.