# How do I know if my browser supports SVG 2.0?

Tags: svg

How do I know if my browser supports SVG 2.0?

(Apart from trying a feature that is supposed to work in SVG2 and realizing it's not working or that it works ...?)

Comment: Check your calendar. When it says 2018, your browser may support SVG 2.

Comment: 2018-01-01 now, but.. it turns out that [SVG 2 is on life support](http://tavmjong.free.fr/svg2_status.html).

Comment: Or perhaps "[after a near death experience, SVG 2 is back."](https://www.patreon.com/posts/svg-2-status-19078074) At least, this [Patreon page](https://www.patreon.com/tavmjong) seems to have some modest support and occasional [updates](https://www.patreon.com/posts/svg-2-update-20335982) and talk of[fallbacks](https://www.patreon.com/posts/svg-2-fallbacks-23506209) that work in conjunction with InkScape exports and browsers.

Comment: [2020-02-16 Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) 2 W3C Editor’s Draft](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/)

Comment: 2023 now. I can't find any resource that says what browsers support it, not even caniuse. I found this nice article (https://cloudfour.com/thinks/so-you-can-set-an-svg-circles-radius-in-css/) which uses the circle `r` in css. I tried it in all major browsers and versions and it works (even on older Safari version such as iOS 11). So seems fine to use.

Answer (score 16):

From what I understand SVG 2.0 is still a work in progress with no full browser implementation.

For the more elusive features of SVG that may not be implemented by all browser you can check [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg) to see if the feature is supported.

Answer (score 14):

Asking if a browser supports SVG 2 is like asking if a browser supports HTML5. It seems like a totally reasonable question, but it doesn't work like that.

The best we can do is test if a browser supports a *feature*, rather than a version of spec.