# Irregular thickness of SVG polygon edges

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a Voronoi treemap and wanted to change the thickness of the polygons on mouseover.

Everything works fine as it is, but in nearly all polygons some of the affected edges have different thickness, although everything should be the same stroke-width.

Some of the polygons seem to work as intended though.

Does anyone know what causes this?

```
  $("polygon[hierarchy=lvl3]")
    .mouseenter(function () {
      $(this)
        .css("stroke-width", 12);
    })
    .mouseleave(function () {
      $(this)
        .css("stroke-width", 2);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r10gxdqd/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polygon is in fact rendering the 12px stroke; the issue is the stacking order.  With HTML, we fix this by specifying a z-index.  However, in SVG, it is entirely based on the order it was rendered (see [How to use z-index in svg elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786618/how-to-use-z-index-in-svg-elements)).

To fix this, in your code, you can simply append the one hovered over to the end of the SVG document, re-rendering it.  See below for demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("polygon[hierarchy=lvl3]")
     .mouseenter(function () {
       $(this)
         .css("stroke-width", 12)
         .appendTo("svg");
     })
     .mouseleave(function () {
       $(this)
         .css("stroke-width", 2);
     });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="800" viewBox="0 0 1932 1092" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="574,6 1148,6 1330,508 1269,703 1044,858 741,877 491,728 412,459 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1268,337 439,552 412,459 574,6 1148,6 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1229,230 1127,265 1100,249 1117,146 1191,124 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="464,312 503,205 590,238 599,300 560,344 " style="fill:#bb6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="692,324 599,300 590,238 642,189 731,240 " style="fill:#00649f;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="821,329 809,261 880,216 928,239 939,306 893,353 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="568,397 560,344 599,300 692,324 705,355 656,426 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="752,232 773,132 865,135 880,216 809,261 " style="fill:#0064b3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="992,196 997,137 1070,115 1117,146 1100,249 1073,255 " style="fill:#00649e;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="656,6 664,113 640,136 539,102 574,6 " style="fill:#0064a5;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="793,460 675,491 656,426 705,355 771,374 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="675,491 545,525 530,444 568,397 656,426 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="752,232 809,261 821,329 771,374 705,355 692,324 731,240 " style="fill:#e16400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="778,6 859,6 873,126 865,135 773,132 763,120 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1229,230 1268,337 1151,367 1127,265 " style="fill:#b76400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="778,6 763,120 664,113 656,6 " style="fill:#0064dd;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="997,137 992,196 928,239 880,216 865,135 873,126 971,114 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1191,124 1117,146 1070,115 1082,6 1148,6 " style="fill:#0064a1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="503,205 539,102 640,136 642,189 590,238 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="545,525 439,552 412,459 426,419 530,444 " style="fill:#db6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="426,419 464,312 560,344 568,397 530,444 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1151,367 1044,395 1022,333 1073,255 1100,249 1127,265 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="910,430 793,460 771,374 821,329 893,353 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="642,189 640,136 664,113 763,120 773,132 752,232 731,240 " style="fill:#0064a1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="859,6 975,6 971,114 873,126 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="939,306 928,239 992,196 1073,255 1022,333 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1044,395 910,430 893,353 939,306 1022,333 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="975,6 1082,6 1070,115 997,137 971,114 " style="fill:#00649f;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="439,552 1268,337 1330,508 1269,703 1044,858 741,877 491,728 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1111,638 1096,702 1008,737 989,729 968,658 996,617 1096,622 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1101,512 1107,507 1192,507 1217,565 1168,633 1111,638 1096,622 " style="fill:#bb6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1049,855 1044,858 926,865 920,772 989,729 1008,737 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="567,773 491,728 475,674 573,631 607,646 620,688 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="545,525 650,497 676,587 607,646 573,631 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="874,439 979,412 1005,506 974,544 897,536 " style="fill:#0064b3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="850,680 878,647 968,658 989,729 920,772 856,742 " style="fill:#00649e;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="739,607 753,655 711,720 620,688 607,646 676,587 " style="fill:#0064a5;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="667,833 567,773 620,688 711,720 719,748 " style="fill:#da6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="979,412 1096,381 1107,507 1101,512 1005,506 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="878,647 850,680 753,655 739,607 785,555 865,570 " style="fill:#e16400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="806,782 719,748 711,720 753,655 850,680 856,742 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="761,468 874,439 897,536 865,570 785,555 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="475,674 439,552 545,525 573,631 " style="fill:#b76400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1160,778 1049,855 1008,737 1096,702 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="810,873 741,877 667,833 719,748 806,782 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="926,865 810,873 806,782 856,742 920,772 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1096,381 1168,362 1212,477 1192,507 1107,507 " style="fill:#0064a8;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="897,536 974,544 996,617 968,658 878,647 865,570 " style="fill:#db6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1243,720 1160,778 1096,702 1111,638 1168,633 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1168,362 1268,337 1310,454 1212,477 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1306,585 1269,703 1243,720 1168,633 1217,565 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1310,454 1330,508 1306,585 1217,565 1192,507 1212,477 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="996,617 974,544 1005,506 1101,512 1096,622 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="650,497 761,468 785,555 739,607 676,587 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1585,1086 1254,1086 1349,845 1582,989 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1585,1086 1254,1086 1349,845 1582,989 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1494,935 1582,989 1585,1086 1474,1086 " style="fill:#bb6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1477,924 1380,989 1306,955 1349,845 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1494,935 1474,1086 1398,1086 1380,989 1477,924 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1398,1086 1254,1086 1306,955 1380,989 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="5,434 5,6 574,6 412,459 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="5,434 5,6 574,6 412,459 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="357,320 329,341 235,324 241,236 274,210 356,242 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="235,324 227,330 119,322 122,222 144,201 241,236 " style="fill:#00649f;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="144,201 146,138 224,105 276,136 274,210 241,236 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="451,350 412,459 330,454 329,341 357,320 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="219,447 227,330 235,324 329,341 330,454 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="113,440 5,434 5,322 118,323 " style="fill:#00649e;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="488,245 397,211 395,135 446,104 527,136 " style="fill:#da6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="451,350 357,320 356,242 397,211 488,245 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="223,6 334,6 334,106 276,136 224,105 " style="fill:#00649c;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="442,6 574,6 527,136 446,104 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="113,440 118,323 119,322 227,330 219,447 " style="fill:#0064ac;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="334,6 442,6 446,104 395,135 334,106 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,204 5,130 114,111 146,138 144,201 122,222 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="116,6 223,6 224,105 146,138 114,111 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,130 5,6 116,6 114,111 " style="fill:#9b6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,322 5,204 122,222 119,322 118,323 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="274,210 276,136 334,106 395,135 397,211 356,242 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="5,777 5,434 412,459 491,728 429,795 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="5,777 5,434 412,459 491,728 429,795 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="363,793 242,787 246,690 343,673 358,687 " style="fill:#0064b1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="211,560 230,576 227,671 127,684 113,670 120,568 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="441,557 474,669 358,687 343,673 343,584 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,675 5,559 105,556 120,568 113,670 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,559 5,434 114,440 105,556 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="123,782 5,777 5,675 113,670 127,684 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="114,440 216,447 211,560 120,568 105,556 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="216,447 323,453 315,561 230,576 211,560 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="246,690 227,671 230,576 315,561 343,584 343,673 " style="fill:#db6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="123,782 127,684 227,671 246,690 242,787 " style="fill:#0064c0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="323,453 412,459 441,557 343,584 315,561 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="363,793 358,687 474,669 491,728 429,795 " style="fill:#0064a4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1098,1086 712,1086 741,877 1044,858 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1098,1086 712,1086 741,877 1044,858 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="727,981 741,877 840,871 849,985 843,992 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="952,864 1044,858 1070,969 966,990 953,978 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="966,1086 845,1086 843,992 849,985 953,978 966,990 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1070,969 1098,1086 966,1086 966,990 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="840,871 952,864 953,978 849,985 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="845,1086 712,1086 727,981 843,992 " style="fill:#0064a8;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1740,6 1926,6 1926,456 1745,372 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1740,6 1926,6 1926,456 1745,372 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1742,126 1740,6 1857,6 1829,125 " style="fill:#0064b1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1926,160 1866,159 1829,125 1857,6 1926,6 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1926,160 1926,305 1863,304 1814,251 1866,159 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1743,250 1742,126 1829,125 1866,159 1814,251 " style="fill:#00649e;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1743,250 1814,251 1863,304 1800,398 1745,372 " style="fill:#00649b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1800,398 1863,304 1926,305 1926,456 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1148,6 1740,6 1745,372 1330,508 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1148,6 1740,6 1745,372 1330,508 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1504,246 1442,218 1440,131 1512,103 1545,123 1558,203 " style="fill:#00649f;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1639,6 1740,6 1742,135 1687,137 1631,86 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1514,323 1504,246 1558,203 1627,227 1647,269 1623,314 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1442,218 1382,251 1324,192 1333,132 1398,106 1440,131 " style="fill:#0064a9;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1742,135 1744,276 1647,269 1627,227 1687,137 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1507,6 1639,6 1631,86 1545,123 1512,103 " style="fill:#0064b0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1229,229 1193,128 1283,92 1333,132 1324,192 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1545,123 1631,86 1687,137 1627,227 1558,203 " style="fill:#0064a1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1448,470 1330,508 1294,410 1407,377 " style="fill:#df6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1288,6 1399,6 1398,106 1333,132 1283,92 " style="fill:#00649c;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1264,327 1229,229 1324,192 1382,251 1377,278 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1294,410 1264,327 1377,278 1418,349 1407,377 " style="fill:#0064a1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1657,401 1623,314 1647,269 1744,276 1745,372 " style="fill:#9b6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1539,440 1512,326 1514,323 1623,314 1657,401 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1288,6 1283,92 1193,128 1148,6 " style="fill:#0064c0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1418,349 1377,278 1382,251 1442,218 1504,246 1514,323 1512,326 " style="fill:#0064e1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1399,6 1507,6 1512,103 1440,131 1398,106 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1539,440 1448,470 1407,377 1418,349 1512,326 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1098,1086 1044,858 1269,703 1349,845 1254,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1098,1086 1044,858 1269,703 1349,845 1254,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1263,946 1179,975 1128,944 1171,826 1225,843 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1144,789 1269,703 1316,787 1225,843 1171,826 " style="fill:#e16400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1178,1086 1098,1086 1066,953 1128,944 1179,975 " style="fill:#0064b1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1316,787 1349,845 1303,962 1263,946 1225,843 " style="fill:#0064bb;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1303,962 1254,1086 1178,1086 1179,975 1263,946 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1144,789 1171,826 1128,944 1066,953 1044,858 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="430,1086 5,1086 5,777 429,795 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="257,788 173,1086 5,1086 5,777 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="131,782 257,788 225,902 128,880 " style="fill:#0064b1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,879 113,892 109,987 5,1025 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,1025 109,987 185,1044 173,1086 5,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="225,902 185,1044 109,987 113,892 128,880 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,879 5,777 131,782 128,880 113,892 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="257,788 429,795 430,1086 173,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="245,833 257,788 429,795 429,837 324,889 " style="fill:#0064b1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="308,1086 308,990 325,975 430,988 430,1086 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="429,837 430,988 325,975 324,889 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="206,968 245,833 324,889 325,975 308,990 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="308,1086 173,1086 206,968 308,990 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1585,1086 1582,989 1926,818 1926,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1585,1086 1582,989 1926,818 1926,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1926,968 1843,964 1806,878 1926,818 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1926,968 1926,1086 1821,1086 1813,1004 1843,964 " style="fill:#00649c;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1821,1086 1679,1086 1695,979 1813,1004 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1675,943 1806,878 1843,964 1813,1004 1695,979 " style="fill:#db6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1679,1086 1585,1086 1582,989 1675,943 1695,979 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="430,1086 429,795 491,728 741,877 712,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="430,1086 429,795 491,728 741,877 712,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="727,977 712,1086 588,1086 638,965 " style="fill:#0064b4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="727,977 638,965 608,927 667,833 741,877 " style="fill:#0064b3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="429,852 429,795 491,728 573,777 525,861 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="430,972 515,971 563,1086 430,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="588,1086 563,1086 515,971 558,922 608,927 638,965 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="429,852 525,861 558,922 515,971 430,972 " style="fill:#0064a8;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="573,777 667,833 608,927 558,922 525,861 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1926,456 1926,818 1582,989 1349,845 1269,703 1330,508 1745,372 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1511,449 1800,881 1582,989 1349,845 1269,703 1330,508 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1509,944 1389,870 1447,799 1501,804 1540,884 " style="fill:#0064b4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1749,805 1800,881 1671,945 1636,865 1640,855 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1401,485 1511,449 1558,518 1473,584 1437,572 " style="fill:#00649f;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1389,870 1349,845 1303,763 1400,716 1408,719 1447,799 " style="fill:#da6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1636,865 1540,884 1501,804 1555,746 1602,757 1640,855 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1671,945 1582,989 1509,944 1540,884 1636,865 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1621,613 1677,697 1602,757 1555,746 1524,674 " style="fill:#e16400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1366,629 1437,572 1473,584 1508,667 1408,719 1400,716 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1401,485 1437,572 1366,629 1298,609 1330,508 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1677,697 1749,805 1640,855 1602,757 " style="fill:#0064a8;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1501,804 1447,799 1408,719 1508,667 1524,674 1555,746 " style="fill:#0064b4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1303,763 1269,703 1298,609 1366,629 1400,716 " style="fill:#0064a4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1621,613 1524,674 1508,667 1473,584 1558,518 " style="fill:#0064bd;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1511,449 1745,372 1926,456 1926,818 1800,881 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1872,431 1926,456 1926,581 1840,573 1808,518 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1732,376 1745,372 1872,431 1808,518 1742,509 " style="fill:#00649e;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1726,770 1665,679 1727,632 1793,646 1817,694 1804,726 " style="fill:#da6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1591,569 1511,449 1625,411 1659,523 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1889,836 1804,726 1817,694 1926,684 1926,818 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1726,770 1804,726 1889,836 1800,881 " style="fill:#e16400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1625,411 1732,376 1742,509 1709,531 1659,523 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1793,646 1727,632 1709,531 1742,509 1808,518 1840,573 " style="fill:#0064a8;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1926,581 1926,684 1817,694 1793,646 1840,573 " style="fill:#0064b4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1665,679 1591,569 1659,523 1709,531 1727,632 " style="fill:#0064a4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, wait.. there's another problem now. If I do it like this, the higher levels of the treemap get overridden. Is there any other way to do this without overriding the higher level polygons or text elements that I still intend to add?

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm following the issue. Could you post a fuller example showing the "higher level"?

Comment: Nvm. I just need to figure out how to move the elements to specific positions. It's another issue and I'll just open another question if I get stuck. It can be accomplished with groups and appending to these though, as I just figured out. So thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the stroke/edge itself, it's the surrounding polygons that hide part of the stroke of the hovered polygon. You can confirm this by hiding the siblings (test below):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //add mouseover event
  $("polygon[hierarchy=lvl3]")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).siblings().hide();
    $(this)
    .css({
      "stroke-width": 12
    });
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {

    $(this).siblings().show();
    $(this)
    .css({
      "stroke-width": 2
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="800" viewBox="0 0 1932 1092" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="574,6 1148,6 1330,508 1269,703 1044,858 741,877 491,728 412,459 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1268,337 439,552 412,459 574,6 1148,6 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1229,230 1127,265 1100,249 1117,146 1191,124 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="464,312 503,205 590,238 599,300 560,344 " style="fill:#bb6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="692,324 599,300 590,238 642,189 731,240 " style="fill:#00649f;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="821,329 809,261 880,216 928,239 939,306 893,353 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="568,397 560,344 599,300 692,324 705,355 656,426 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="752,232 773,132 865,135 880,216 809,261 " style="fill:#0064b3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="992,196 997,137 1070,115 1117,146 1100,249 1073,255 " style="fill:#00649e;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="656,6 664,113 640,136 539,102 574,6 " style="fill:#0064a5;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="793,460 675,491 656,426 705,355 771,374 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="675,491 545,525 530,444 568,397 656,426 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="752,232 809,261 821,329 771,374 705,355 692,324 731,240 " style="fill:#e16400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="778,6 859,6 873,126 865,135 773,132 763,120 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1229,230 1268,337 1151,367 1127,265 " style="fill:#b76400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="778,6 763,120 664,113 656,6 " style="fill:#0064dd;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="997,137 992,196 928,239 880,216 865,135 873,126 971,114 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1191,124 1117,146 1070,115 1082,6 1148,6 " style="fill:#0064a1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="503,205 539,102 640,136 642,189 590,238 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="545,525 439,552 412,459 426,419 530,444 " style="fill:#db6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="426,419 464,312 560,344 568,397 530,444 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1151,367 1044,395 1022,333 1073,255 1100,249 1127,265 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="910,430 793,460 771,374 821,329 893,353 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="642,189 640,136 664,113 763,120 773,132 752,232 731,240 " style="fill:#0064a1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="859,6 975,6 971,114 873,126 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="939,306 928,239 992,196 1073,255 1022,333 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1044,395 910,430 893,353 939,306 1022,333 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="975,6 1082,6 1070,115 997,137 971,114 " style="fill:#00649f;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="439,552 1268,337 1330,508 1269,703 1044,858 741,877 491,728 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1111,638 1096,702 1008,737 989,729 968,658 996,617 1096,622 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1101,512 1107,507 1192,507 1217,565 1168,633 1111,638 1096,622 " style="fill:#bb6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1049,855 1044,858 926,865 920,772 989,729 1008,737 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="567,773 491,728 475,674 573,631 607,646 620,688 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="545,525 650,497 676,587 607,646 573,631 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="874,439 979,412 1005,506 974,544 897,536 " style="fill:#0064b3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="850,680 878,647 968,658 989,729 920,772 856,742 " style="fill:#00649e;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="739,607 753,655 711,720 620,688 607,646 676,587 " style="fill:#0064a5;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="667,833 567,773 620,688 711,720 719,748 " style="fill:#da6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="979,412 1096,381 1107,507 1101,512 1005,506 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="878,647 850,680 753,655 739,607 785,555 865,570 " style="fill:#e16400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="806,782 719,748 711,720 753,655 850,680 856,742 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="761,468 874,439 897,536 865,570 785,555 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="475,674 439,552 545,525 573,631 " style="fill:#b76400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1160,778 1049,855 1008,737 1096,702 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="810,873 741,877 667,833 719,748 806,782 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="926,865 810,873 806,782 856,742 920,772 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1096,381 1168,362 1212,477 1192,507 1107,507 " style="fill:#0064a8;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="897,536 974,544 996,617 968,658 878,647 865,570 " style="fill:#db6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1243,720 1160,778 1096,702 1111,638 1168,633 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1168,362 1268,337 1310,454 1212,477 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1306,585 1269,703 1243,720 1168,633 1217,565 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1310,454 1330,508 1306,585 1217,565 1192,507 1212,477 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="996,617 974,544 1005,506 1101,512 1096,622 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="650,497 761,468 785,555 739,607 676,587 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1585,1086 1254,1086 1349,845 1582,989 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1585,1086 1254,1086 1349,845 1582,989 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1494,935 1582,989 1585,1086 1474,1086 " style="fill:#bb6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1477,924 1380,989 1306,955 1349,845 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1494,935 1474,1086 1398,1086 1380,989 1477,924 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1398,1086 1254,1086 1306,955 1380,989 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="5,434 5,6 574,6 412,459 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="5,434 5,6 574,6 412,459 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="357,320 329,341 235,324 241,236 274,210 356,242 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="235,324 227,330 119,322 122,222 144,201 241,236 " style="fill:#00649f;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="144,201 146,138 224,105 276,136 274,210 241,236 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="451,350 412,459 330,454 329,341 357,320 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="219,447 227,330 235,324 329,341 330,454 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="113,440 5,434 5,322 118,323 " style="fill:#00649e;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="488,245 397,211 395,135 446,104 527,136 " style="fill:#da6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="451,350 357,320 356,242 397,211 488,245 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="223,6 334,6 334,106 276,136 224,105 " style="fill:#00649c;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="442,6 574,6 527,136 446,104 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="113,440 118,323 119,322 227,330 219,447 " style="fill:#0064ac;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="334,6 442,6 446,104 395,135 334,106 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,204 5,130 114,111 146,138 144,201 122,222 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="116,6 223,6 224,105 146,138 114,111 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,130 5,6 116,6 114,111 " style="fill:#9b6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,322 5,204 122,222 119,322 118,323 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="274,210 276,136 334,106 395,135 397,211 356,242 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="5,777 5,434 412,459 491,728 429,795 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="5,777 5,434 412,459 491,728 429,795 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="363,793 242,787 246,690 343,673 358,687 " style="fill:#0064b1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="211,560 230,576 227,671 127,684 113,670 120,568 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="441,557 474,669 358,687 343,673 343,584 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,675 5,559 105,556 120,568 113,670 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,559 5,434 114,440 105,556 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="123,782 5,777 5,675 113,670 127,684 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="114,440 216,447 211,560 120,568 105,556 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="216,447 323,453 315,561 230,576 211,560 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="246,690 227,671 230,576 315,561 343,584 343,673 " style="fill:#db6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="123,782 127,684 227,671 246,690 242,787 " style="fill:#0064c0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="323,453 412,459 441,557 343,584 315,561 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="363,793 358,687 474,669 491,728 429,795 " style="fill:#0064a4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1098,1086 712,1086 741,877 1044,858 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1098,1086 712,1086 741,877 1044,858 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="727,981 741,877 840,871 849,985 843,992 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="952,864 1044,858 1070,969 966,990 953,978 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="966,1086 845,1086 843,992 849,985 953,978 966,990 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1070,969 1098,1086 966,1086 966,990 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="840,871 952,864 953,978 849,985 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="845,1086 712,1086 727,981 843,992 " style="fill:#0064a8;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1740,6 1926,6 1926,456 1745,372 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1740,6 1926,6 1926,456 1745,372 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1742,126 1740,6 1857,6 1829,125 " style="fill:#0064b1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1926,160 1866,159 1829,125 1857,6 1926,6 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1926,160 1926,305 1863,304 1814,251 1866,159 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1743,250 1742,126 1829,125 1866,159 1814,251 " style="fill:#00649e;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1743,250 1814,251 1863,304 1800,398 1745,372 " style="fill:#00649b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1800,398 1863,304 1926,305 1926,456 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1148,6 1740,6 1745,372 1330,508 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1148,6 1740,6 1745,372 1330,508 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1504,246 1442,218 1440,131 1512,103 1545,123 1558,203 " style="fill:#00649f;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1639,6 1740,6 1742,135 1687,137 1631,86 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1514,323 1504,246 1558,203 1627,227 1647,269 1623,314 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1442,218 1382,251 1324,192 1333,132 1398,106 1440,131 " style="fill:#0064a9;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1742,135 1744,276 1647,269 1627,227 1687,137 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1507,6 1639,6 1631,86 1545,123 1512,103 " style="fill:#0064b0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1229,229 1193,128 1283,92 1333,132 1324,192 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1545,123 1631,86 1687,137 1627,227 1558,203 " style="fill:#0064a1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1448,470 1330,508 1294,410 1407,377 " style="fill:#df6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1288,6 1399,6 1398,106 1333,132 1283,92 " style="fill:#00649c;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1264,327 1229,229 1324,192 1382,251 1377,278 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1294,410 1264,327 1377,278 1418,349 1407,377 " style="fill:#0064a1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1657,401 1623,314 1647,269 1744,276 1745,372 " style="fill:#9b6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1539,440 1512,326 1514,323 1623,314 1657,401 " style="fill:#00649d;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1288,6 1283,92 1193,128 1148,6 " style="fill:#0064c0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1418,349 1377,278 1382,251 1442,218 1504,246 1514,323 1512,326 " style="fill:#0064e1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1399,6 1507,6 1512,103 1440,131 1398,106 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1539,440 1448,470 1407,377 1418,349 1512,326 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1098,1086 1044,858 1269,703 1349,845 1254,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1098,1086 1044,858 1269,703 1349,845 1254,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1263,946 1179,975 1128,944 1171,826 1225,843 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1144,789 1269,703 1316,787 1225,843 1171,826 " style="fill:#e16400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1178,1086 1098,1086 1066,953 1128,944 1179,975 " style="fill:#0064b1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1316,787 1349,845 1303,962 1263,946 1225,843 " style="fill:#0064bb;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1303,962 1254,1086 1178,1086 1179,975 1263,946 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1144,789 1171,826 1128,944 1066,953 1044,858 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="430,1086 5,1086 5,777 429,795 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="257,788 173,1086 5,1086 5,777 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="131,782 257,788 225,902 128,880 " style="fill:#0064b1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,879 113,892 109,987 5,1025 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,1025 109,987 185,1044 173,1086 5,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="225,902 185,1044 109,987 113,892 128,880 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="5,879 5,777 131,782 128,880 113,892 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="257,788 429,795 430,1086 173,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="245,833 257,788 429,795 429,837 324,889 " style="fill:#0064b1;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="308,1086 308,990 325,975 430,988 430,1086 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="429,837 430,988 325,975 324,889 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="206,968 245,833 324,889 325,975 308,990 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="308,1086 173,1086 206,968 308,990 " style="fill:#0064a0;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1585,1086 1582,989 1926,818 1926,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1585,1086 1582,989 1926,818 1926,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1926,968 1843,964 1806,878 1926,818 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1926,968 1926,1086 1821,1086 1813,1004 1843,964 " style="fill:#00649c;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1821,1086 1679,1086 1695,979 1813,1004 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1675,943 1806,878 1843,964 1813,1004 1695,979 " style="fill:#db6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1679,1086 1585,1086 1582,989 1675,943 1695,979 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="430,1086 429,795 491,728 741,877 712,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="430,1086 429,795 491,728 741,877 712,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="727,977 712,1086 588,1086 638,965 " style="fill:#0064b4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="727,977 638,965 608,927 667,833 741,877 " style="fill:#0064b3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="429,852 429,795 491,728 573,777 525,861 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="430,972 515,971 563,1086 430,1086 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="588,1086 563,1086 515,971 558,922 608,927 638,965 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="429,852 525,861 558,922 515,971 430,972 " style="fill:#0064a8;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="573,777 667,833 608,927 558,922 525,861 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl1" points="1926,456 1926,818 1582,989 1349,845 1269,703 1330,508 1745,372 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:12.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1511,449 1800,881 1582,989 1349,845 1269,703 1330,508 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1509,944 1389,870 1447,799 1501,804 1540,884 " style="fill:#0064b4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1749,805 1800,881 1671,945 1636,865 1640,855 " style="fill:#0064a3;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1401,485 1511,449 1558,518 1473,584 1437,572 " style="fill:#00649f;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1389,870 1349,845 1303,763 1400,716 1408,719 1447,799 " style="fill:#da6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1636,865 1540,884 1501,804 1555,746 1602,757 1640,855 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1671,945 1582,989 1509,944 1540,884 1636,865 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1621,613 1677,697 1602,757 1555,746 1524,674 " style="fill:#e16400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1366,629 1437,572 1473,584 1508,667 1408,719 1400,716 " style="fill:#0064a6;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1401,485 1437,572 1366,629 1298,609 1330,508 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1677,697 1749,805 1640,855 1602,757 " style="fill:#0064a8;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1501,804 1447,799 1408,719 1508,667 1524,674 1555,746 " style="fill:#0064b4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1303,763 1269,703 1298,609 1366,629 1400,716 " style="fill:#0064a4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1621,613 1524,674 1508,667 1473,584 1558,518 " style="fill:#0064bd;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl2" points="1511,449 1745,372 1926,456 1926,818 1800,881 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:6.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1872,431 1926,456 1926,581 1840,573 1808,518 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1732,376 1745,372 1872,431 1808,518 1742,509 " style="fill:#00649e;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1726,770 1665,679 1727,632 1793,646 1817,694 1804,726 " style="fill:#da6400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1591,569 1511,449 1625,411 1659,523 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1889,836 1804,726 1817,694 1926,684 1926,818 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1726,770 1804,726 1889,836 1800,881 " style="fill:#e16400;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1625,411 1732,376 1742,509 1709,531 1659,523 " style="fill:#9b9b9b;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1793,646 1727,632 1709,531 1742,509 1808,518 1840,573 " style="fill:#0064a8;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1926,581 1926,684 1817,694 1793,646 1840,573 " style="fill:#0064b4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
  <polygon hierarchy="lvl3" points="1665,679 1591,569 1659,523 1709,531 1727,632 " style="fill:#0064a4;stroke:black;stroke-width:2.0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: But shouldn't all the siblings hide the same amount of the strokes, since all of them have the same stroke-width?

Comment: @Stasz as [allicarm explained below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34068693/1326147), the svg is built with a predefined area for all the polygons, once you change the size of that area (i.e. you're increasing the area of one specific poligon that is hovered), if you want that same polygon to be totally visible you need to append the new part (the new stroke width) to the svg.

Comment: @Stasz if the polygon that you hover is the last one among the surrounding ones (in the code), then all of them hide the same amount of its edges. If the hovered polygon is the first one among the surrounding ones, then its edges hide part of those polygons. So the irregular behavior happens in polygons that are not the first or last among their surroundings. Btw, you can mark this question as answered by allicarn and create a new one with the question about overriding the higher level polygons (include the new code in there, no need to edit this question any further).