# Z-Index only working on a IE browser

Tags: css, html

I am having trouble with z-index and the compatibility with all browsers except IE, the first thing I tried was setting all the positions but no luck, hopefully someone with more experience than I can assist me. Please visit the link to find the code https://jsfiddle.net/my3hr7dv/2/

```css
#container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}


#header    {
 width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-right: 10%;
 z-index: 2;
}

#leftNav {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 height: 90%;
 background-color: #03f;
 border-right: 1px dashed #694717; /* Delete once layout has been set */
 z-index: 1;
}

#rightNav {
 float: right;
 width: 20%;
 height: 90%;
 background-color: #03f;
 border-left: 1px dashed; /* Delete once layout has been set */
 z-index: 1;
}

#canvas {
 margin:auto;
 width: 60%;
 position: relative;
}

#footer {
 clear: both;
 background-color: #867E7E;
 height: 0%;
}

body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #a3a3c2; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#a3a3c2, #d1d1e0); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#a3a3c2, #d1d1e0); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#a3a3c2, #d1d1e0); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#a3a3c2, #d1d1e0); /* Standard syntax */
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}


#top {
 width: 100%;
 height: 2%;
 background-color: #111;
 position: relative;
}

svg{
 z-index: 3;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="header">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <svg height="100%" width="100%">
      <circle cx="50%" cy="-20" r="40" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" fill="black" /> 
    </svg> 
   </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="leftNav">This is the sites leftnav</div> 
  <div id="rightNav">This is the sites rightnav</div> 
  <div id="canvas"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

please note some of the page gets cut off on js fiddle but this does not happen in the browsers I am using. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>` is not a valid doctype, I'm pretty sure. If you want HTML5 you should use `<!doctype html>`. Anyway, what, specifically, is your problem? "having trouble with z-index" isn't very clear.

Comment: Also, there's no question here. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can't use `z-index` on SVG elements; they're designed to be placed per their order in the DOM.

Comment: my problem is that the layering is only working on IE and not on chrome and firefox, as you can see <https://gyazo.com/0db30fe98a8d1edf932a8d1d8cee7aa5> on IE it works, however, it looks like this on the other browsers <https://gyazo.com/caa4a4d18698b2b1bc76ef6f2041b4f4>

Answer (score 4):

`#leftNav` and `#rightNav` are not positioned.
Without `position: relative` or `position: absolute` on an element you can't use z-index (or more like: it won't have an effect).

Only with positioning the object absolutely or relatively you create a stacking context in which you can stack elements on top of each other with z-index.

Edit:
In order to create a stacking context you could also go for position: fixed or (in suporting browsers) position: sticky. Or to turn the stick around: any position value will create a stacking context and you can use z-index in combination with it apart from `position: static`.

Edit2:
If you wanted to put the SVG on top of the `#header` by setting some z-index on it, I have to tell you that this is impossible to do so. =( Unfortunately there is something in the spec explaining the issue: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/render.html#RenderingOrder

Comment: Any `position` other than `static` will do, actually.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?
The `#header` needs to be on top of the two navs and the SVG needs to be on top of the `#header`. Right?

Comment: @TylerH, meaning the position `fixed` will also do the job. In other words, the element must be placed out of flow in order the `z-index` can take effect.

Comment: @skobaljic Yes, and `position: sticky` in browsers that already support it.

Comment: @skobaljic & TylerH
you're both right, I'll add that to my comment. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @TylerH, thanks for [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) note, learned something new today.

Comment: These have been tried but makes no difference to the position of the circle gyazo.com/caa4a4d18698b2b1bc76ef6f2041b4f4 and like it should in IE gyazo.com/0db30fe98a8d1edf932a8d1d8cee7aa5

Comment: @RyanEvans See my second edit. You can't position SVGs and stack them with z-index. You'd have to wrap the SVG inside a container and position that. Makes it a bit of a hassle but it's the only workaround I could think of at the moment.

Comment: @MarcoHengstenberg i shall try that now thanks for your help

Comment: @RyanEvans happy to help =)

Answer (score 0):

Have a read at [z-index stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Css z-index is a bit tricky and counter-intuitive until you really understand it

---

Also as tyler has said, you can't use `z-index` on `svg`-Tags [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786618/how-to-use-z-index-in-svg-elements).
If you only need svg for the circle you could try

```
.myCircleDiv
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/my3hr7dv/3/)

Comment: Ended up using the circle you sent me with a few alterations, works perfectly now, svg was nice but not what I needed thanks for all the help =)

Comment: Upvote and correct answer would be appreciated in that case ;)