# Directive execution order in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

If I have a simple button with a click handler and a custom attribute directive like so:

```
<button  (click)="save()" attributedirective="project saved">Save</button>
```

And in my attribute directive I'm using the hostlistener decorator to listen to the click event:

```
@Directive({
    selector: `[attributedirective]`
})
export class AuditPusher {
    @Input('attributedirective') attributedirective: string = 'Missing message!';

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    pushAudit() {
        console.log('text:'+this.attributedirective.toString());
    }
}
```

Which of my code will fire first? The save() on the click event or the code in my attribute directive? - And: Imagine having two attribute directives. Which of those will fire first? In Angular 1 there was something like directive priorities, how is this done in Angular 2? I find it difficult to find documentation on this.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the order of execution is undefined. You shouldn't depend on a specific order.

Comment: No, that's also not defined as far as I know and explicitely so.

Answer (score 3):

I think priority concept is yet not there in Angular2. (If it is already i'm not aware of it yet) but One should not depend on a specific order as already said.

But as you have asked specifically. Order would be,

1)when page or a component is loaded, `<button  (click)="save()" attributedirective="project saved">Save</button>` is loaded too and because of directive**(attributedirective) is attached to **button**, Angular2 **initializes directive**(attributedirective) and **binds** it to button.

2) As **Save()** is a function attached to native click (Angular2's way) event of button if you click it, it will call **save()** first and then it will look for other **binding's events(if any)** attached to it (eg.`pushAudit`)

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way around this when I had two attribute directives and Angular was executing `DirectiveB` before `DirectiveA` but I needed to have it the other way around was to delay the stuff I needed to execute last:

```
export class DirectiveA {
    ngOnInit() {
        doStuff();
    }
}

export class DirectiveB {
    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            doMoreStuff();
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

When you do `setTimeout(0)` it will defer execution to the next Angular processing cycle, which is just what I needed in my case for everything in `DirectiveA` to be set up in time in order to handle events coming from `DirectiveB`.

Comment: check out ApplicationRef.tick() instead of setTimeout(0)

Comment: Yup that could work too. I've come across it before but didn't end up using it, I'll give it a try next time, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but for me it worked like this:
I have an svg:g element and added 2 directives like this:

In order to execute directiveB first in the module at the exports section I added directiveB first and after directiveA.

Note that for svg the z-index is defined by the order the element appears in the document. [How to use z-index in svg elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786618/how-to-use-z-index-in-svg-elements).

I know you have a click there and a custom attribute but if you have 2 custom attributes this can work!