# SVG rendering order issue needs to be resolved without any JS

Tags: css, svg

I have been experimenting with inline svg for the first time. Here is my code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="350" height="350">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .ring {
        transform-origin: 175px 175px;
      }

      .ring.a {
        fill: #f2ca30;
      }
      .ring.b {
        fill: #31bc06;
      }
      .ring.c {
        fill: #11a0ad;
        }
      .ring.d {
        fill: #028d9e;
      }

      .btn.tap.area {
        z-index: 100;
        fill: transparent;
      }
      .btn.tap.area:hover + .ring.container .ring {
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }

      .btn.tap.area:hover + .ring.container .ring.a,
      .btn.tap.area:hover + .ring.container .ring.c {
        animation-name: clockwise;
      }
      .btn.tap.area:hover + .ring.container .ring.b,
      .btn.tap.area:hover + .ring.container .ring.d {
        animation-name: counter-clockwise;
      }

      .btn.tap.area:hover + .ring.container .ring.a {
        animation-duration: 1.33s;
      }
      .btn.tap.area:hover + .ring.container .ring.b {
        animation-duration: 1s;
      }
      .btn.tap.area:hover + .ring.container .ring.c {
        animation-duration: .67s;
      }
      .btn.tap.area:hover + .ring.container .ring.d {
        animation-duration: .33s;
      }

      @keyframes clockwise {
        from {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
      @keyframes counter-clockwise {
        from {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
          transform: rotate(-360deg);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <title>ring btn</title>
  <rect class="btn tap area" width="350" height="350"/>
  <g class="ring container">
    <path class="ring a" d="M119.139,129.639a10.5,10.5,0,0,1-7.425-17.924,89.5,89.5,0,0,1,126.571,0,10.5,10.5,0,0,1-14.849,14.85,68.5,68.5,0,0,0-96.873,0A10.468,10.468,0,0,1,119.139,129.639Z"/>
    <path class="ring b" d="M104.29,114.79a10.5,10.5,0,0,1-7.425-17.924,110.5,110.5,0,0,1,156.269,0,10.5,10.5,0,1,1-14.849,14.85,89.5,89.5,0,0,0-126.57,0A10.468,10.468,0,0,1,104.29,114.79Z"/>
    <path class="ring c" d="M89.44,99.94a10.5,10.5,0,0,1-7.424-17.925,131.5,131.5,0,0,1,185.967,0,10.5,10.5,0,1,1-14.849,14.85,110.5,110.5,0,0,0-156.27,0A10.468,10.468,0,0,1,89.44,99.94Z"/>
    <path class="ring d" d="M74.591,85.091a10.5,10.5,0,0,1-7.425-17.925,152.5,152.5,0,0,1,215.667,0,10.5,10.5,0,1,1-14.849,14.85,131.5,131.5,0,0,0-185.968,0A10.468,10.468,0,0,1,74.591,85.091Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

At a first glance this btn seems to work fine once you `:hover` into the `.btn.tap.area` I have defined. But if your cursor happens to get in the way of one of the animated `.ring` paths then the animation seems to get re-triggered and starts again.

I would like sole this re-triggering issue without any JS.

My solution to this was to put the transparent `.btn.tap.area` atop of the other paths in the svg.

I can't change the rendering order of my svg paths as I am relying on it in the css e.g. `.btn.tap.area:hover + .ring.container .ring.a {`.

As I understand it `z-index` isn't valid in the context of svg, so I cannot use that.

I then saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786618/how-to-use-z-index-in-svg-elements) and thought that the alternative solution offered would work: `<use xlink:href="#btnID"/>` would call up a second instance of the `.btn.tap.area` path once I had added an id of `btnID` to `.btn.tap.area`. But this didn't seem to work either.

Is there another solution to force the `.btn.tap.area` in front of the other paths without using any JS?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nuw82/62/) to see the issue for yourself.

Comment: place your rect inside the g.container, set your CSS :hover rules on the g element and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add pointer-events: none; to the ring elements e.g.

```
  .ring {
    transform-origin: 175px 175px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

Comment: Wow! A gap in my learning. I can't believe how simple this solution is. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change svg elements order with z-index. But you can do it with HTML elements. What about the following solution :

I put the tap-area in another absolutely-positioned svg.

```css
  .svg-stack {
    position: relative;
  }
      
  .svg-tap-area {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
      
  .ring {
    transform-origin: 175px 175px;
  }

  .ring.a {
    fill: #f2ca30;
  }

  .ring.b {
    fill: #31bc06;
  }

  .ring.c {
    fill: #11a0ad;
  }

  .ring.d {
    fill: #028d9e;
  }

  .btn.tap.area {
    fill: transparent;
  }

  .svg-tap-area:hover + svg .ring.container .ring {
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }

  .svg-tap-area:hover + svg .ring.container .ring.a,
  .svg-tap-area:hover + svg .ring.container .ring.c {
    animation-name: clockwise;
  }

  .svg-tap-area:hover + svg .ring.container .ring.b,
  .svg-tap-area:hover + svg .ring.container .ring.d {
    animation-name: counter-clockwise;
  }

  .svg-tap-area:hover + svg .ring.container .ring.a {
    animation-duration: 1.33s;
  }

  .svg-tap-area:hover + svg .ring.container .ring.b {
    animation-duration: 1s;
  }

  .svg-tap-area:hover + svg .ring.container .ring.c {
    animation-duration: .67s;
  }

  .svg-tap-area:hover + svg .ring.container .ring.d {
    animation-duration: .33s;
  }

  @keyframes clockwise {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes counter-clockwise {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="svg-stack">
  <svg class="svg-tap-area" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="350" height="350">
    <title>ring area</title>
    <rect class="btn tap area" id="one" width="350" height="350"/>
  </svg>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="350" height="350">
    <title>ring btn</title>
    <g class="ring container">
      <path class="ring a" d="M119.139,129.639a10.5,10.5,0,0,1-7.425-17.924,89.5,89.5,0,0,1,126.571,0,10.5,10.5,0,0,1-14.849,14.85,68.5,68.5,0,0,0-96.873,0A10.468,10.468,0,0,1,119.139,129.639Z"/>
      <path class="ring b" d="M104.29,114.79a10.5,10.5,0,0,1-7.425-17.924,110.5,110.5,0,0,1,156.269,0,10.5,10.5,0,1,1-14.849,14.85,89.5,89.5,0,0,0-126.57,0A10.468,10.468,0,0,1,104.29,114.79Z"/>
      <path class="ring c" d="M89.44,99.94a10.5,10.5,0,0,1-7.424-17.925,131.5,131.5,0,0,1,185.967,0,10.5,10.5,0,1,1-14.849,14.85,110.5,110.5,0,0,0-156.27,0A10.468,10.468,0,0,1,89.44,99.94Z"/>
      <path class="ring d" d="M74.591,85.091a10.5,10.5,0,0,1-7.425-17.925,152.5,152.5,0,0,1,215.667,0,10.5,10.5,0,1,1-14.849,14.85,131.5,131.5,0,0,0-185.968,0A10.468,10.468,0,0,1,74.591,85.091Z"/>
    </g>
    <rect class="btn tap area" id="one" width="350" height="350"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```