# Transparent overlapping circles without border in background

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to implement transparent overlapping [svg circle elements](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_circle.asp) without circles border in transparent area?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use z-index in svg elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786618/how-to-use-z-index-in-svg-elements)

Comment: svg circles have the ability to set start and stop angles, so it should definitely be possible with a little math. You could also just set a z-index with a background, which would be easier.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide z-index wouldn't help, because circles are transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clip the bits you don't want to draw...

```html
<svg height="100" width="150">
  <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <rect width="0.79" height="1.2" x="-0.1" y="-0.1"/>
      </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" opacity="0.2" />
  <circle cx="80" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute) to view information about position absolute css code.  I think this is what you are looking for.  You might also want to view information about z-index.  If you have any questions or want me to write some sample code for your problem let me know

```css
svg{
position: absolute;
}

#svg-1{
    top: 80px;
    left: 20px;
}

#svg-2{
    top: 80px;
    left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg-1" height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg> 
  <svg id="svg-2" height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>
```

Comment: they don't seem very transparent.

Comment: lol sorry I didn't realize that was the problem.  Give me a minute to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `<mask>`.

I've used the same elements as @RobertLongson's answer so you can compare the approaches.

```html
<svg height="100" width="150">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <!-- white rectangle to keep the area outside the circle -->
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <!-- black circle creates a "hole" to hide the part inside -->
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" opacity="0.2" />
  <circle cx="80" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none"
          mask="url(#mask)"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```