# Constrain enter/exit events to only background div in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to display a moving cross hairs with coordinates when the cursor is moved over a particular DIV containing an SVG.

On `mouseenter` I can successfully create a `rect` displaying the coordinates (and remove it on `mouseout`), however, moving the cursor over the newly created `rect` or text itself fires a `mouseout` `mouseenter` event cycle.

I've tried `d3.event.stopPropagation()` in several places, but none seem to work.

The picture shows if you carefully move the mouse onto the grey "screen" - the rect & text is created and stays in one place.

But if you move the cursor to touch "bobo" or the green rectangle, it starts moving.

[image]

```
var infoBox = null;

var theSVG = d3.select("#theScreen")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 250)
  .attr("height", 250);

// Register mouse events
theSVG
  .on("mouseenter", mouseEnter)
  .on("mouseout",   mouseExit);

function mouseEnter()
{
    if (infoBox !== null)
      return;

  var coord = d3.mouse(d3.event.currentTarget);
  x1 = parseInt(coord[0]);
  y1 = parseInt(coord[1]);

  console.log("mouseEnter", x1, y1, infoBox);

  infoBox = theSVG.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'ssInfoBox');

  var rectItem = infoBox.append("rect")
  .attr('x', x1)
  .attr('y', y1)
  .attr('width',  30)
  .attr('height', 20);

  var textItem = infoBox.append("text")
  .attr('x', x1)
  .attr('y', y1)
  .text("bobo");
}

function mouseExit()
{
    if (infoBox === null)
    return;

    console.log("mouseExit", infoBox);
  infoBox.remove()
  infoBox = null;
}
```

The code doesn't implement the moving yet. To start, I just want the rect/text created and destroyed on `mouseenter` and `mouseout`.

How do I do that?

[Link to Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/20yt79uv/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `mouseout`, use `mouseleave`.

The MDN has a good explanation about the differences between them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event

And here is your code with that change only:

```js
var infoBox = null;

var theSVG = d3.select("#theScreen")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 250)
  .attr("height", 250);

// Register mouse events
theSVG
  .on("mouseenter", mouseEnter)
  .on("mouseleave", mouseExit);

function mouseEnter() {
  if (infoBox !== null)
    return;

  var coord = d3.mouse(d3.event.currentTarget);
  x1 = parseInt(coord[0]);
  y1 = parseInt(coord[1]);

  console.log("mouseEnter", x1, y1, infoBox);

  infoBox = theSVG.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'ssInfoBox');

  var rectItem = infoBox.append("rect")
    .attr('x', x1)
    .attr('y', y1)
    .attr('width', 30)
    .attr('height', 20);

  var textItem = infoBox.append("text")
    .attr('x', x1)
    .attr('y', y1)
    .text("bobo");
}

function mouseExit() {
  if (infoBox === null)
    return;

  console.log("mouseExit", infoBox);
  infoBox.remove()
  infoBox = null;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #0BB;
}

#theScreen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #333;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.ssInfoBox rect {
  fill: #383;
}

.ssInfoBox text {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <div id='theScreen'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create transparent `div` or any other tag on top of your `svg` with same size. Than handle mouse events of this overlay. 
This way you will not going be interrupted by internal components events. 
Downside - you will have to handle interaction with internals manually.

Like so:

```
<svg style="z-index:1;position:absolute;left:0;width:200px;top:0;height:200px">...</svg>

<div id="overlay" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0);z-index:2;position:absolute;left:0;width:200px;top:0;height:200px"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is when the mouse moves over top of the created text or rect.  This generates a mouseout event which I don't want...

Comment: It will not, if you'll put overlay with higher ```z-index```.

Comment: Seems that SVG doesn't support `z-index`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786618/how-to-use-z-index-in-svg-elements

Comment: ```z-index``` is general css supported by any tag. The overlay must be out of SVG!
```
<svg style="z-index:1;position:absolute;left:0;width:200px;top:0;height:200px">...</svg>
<div id="overlay" style="z-index:2;position:absolute;left:0;width:200px;top:0;height:200px"></div>
```