# Red border in transparent ellipse if affected by the opacity of the container

Tags: html, svg

this code

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100% 100%" width="100%" height="400px">
        <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
            <ellipse cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="100" ry="150" stroke="red" stroke-width="10"/>
        </mask>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0.7"/>  
    </svg>
```

return this as a result

[image: result]

I want to have this same result, but with a red border instead of gray in the ellipse and that this is not affected by the opacity of the rect.

I also need the inside of the ellipse to be transparent (not white) and that it is not affected by the opacity of the rect.

Is this possible?

Comment: 1. You have an invalid viewBox attribute: viewbox="0 0 100% 100%" Use something like this instead: `viewBox="0 0 320 320"`. 2. For the hole remove `stroke="red" stroke-width="10"` from the ellipse, use the ellipse at the end of the svg element and add the `stroke="red" stroke-width="10"` to the `<use>` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking whether you can include a red ellipse as part of your mask, then the answer is no.  Any colours in a mask are converted to alpha values.

If you want a red ellipse around your "hole", then you need to add it as a separate element on top of the rect.

```css
body {
   background-color: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100% 100%" width="100%" height="400px">
    <defs>
        <!-- pull ellipse out as a reusable shape. Used by mask and for red border. -->
        <ellipse id="one" cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="100" ry="150"/>

        <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
            <use xlink:href="#one" fill="black"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0.7"/>  
    <use xlink:href="#one" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="10"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is ``xlink:`` still required?? Used to be that only Apple Safari/iOS still required it: https://css-tricks.com/on-xlinkhref-being-deprecated-in-svg/

Comment: Depends whether you want it to work for anyone still running an older browser version.

Answer (score 0):

for set order you can use tag `use` with the attribute `xlink:href` for more detail see this [How to use z-index in svg elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786618/how-to-use-z-index-in-svg-elements)

add `fill="#fff"` tag and `id="one"` to ellipse and draw it again with `<use xlink:href="#one"/>`

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100% 100%" width="100%" height="400px">
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
        <ellipse id="one" cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="100" ry="150" stroke="red" fill="#fff" stroke-width="10"/>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0.7"/>  
    <use xlink:href="#one"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my friend, but I need the inside of the circle to be transparent (not white) and that it is not affected by the opacity of the rect.